# How do I change languages in Windows 7 Starter Edition?

Tags: language, windows-7

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Starter Edition. What is the procedure for changing the language setting from Spanish to English?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the display language of a Windows installation is only supported in Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise.  On other editions (possibly not Starter, as it has strange restrictions, but certainly Home and Professional builds) you can install a Language Interface Pack, but this only translates a small portion of the most commonly used interface elements.  Please see [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages) for downloads and further details.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/index.html), it lets you change language on pretty much any windows version including windows 7 starter:

> This tool allows you to change display language in Windows editions other than (officially supported) Ultimate, like Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium and Business/Professional.
>
> Vistalizator overrides the limit of one MUI language on non-Ultimate Windows editions.

Step by step installation instructions [here](http://www.froggie.sk/screens.html).